# Orientation is not changing in Java Printing

Tags: java, swing

I want to print jpanel with landscape printing. I tried following code but texts are not printing properly. If I removed `pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);` then it will printing in Portrait page. What is the procedure to print in landscape ?

```
if(arg0.getActionCommand().equals("print")){
            final PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
             job.setJobName("Printing");

             job.setPrintable (new Printable() {    
                public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum){
                    if (pageNum > 0){
                    return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
                    }
                    pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
                    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pg;                
                    g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
                    panel01.printAll(g2);
                    return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
                }
             });
             boolean ok = job.printDialog();
             if (ok) {
                 try { 
                      job.print();
                 } catch (PrinterException ex) {

                 }
        }
```

Comment: Errr shouldn't you *use* that `pf` somewhere after you've it its properties?

Comment: Then how it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `job.setPageable(yourImplementationOfPageableHere)`. Then you can implement

```
PageFormat getPageFormat(int pageIndex)
```

method of the interface to return desired page format for each page.